# Bitbucket file change logs

Tags: bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

Is it possible to get file change logs /commits list or latest commit at particular branch at specified file path?
I tried using /commits/?path={filepath}&until={branch -name}.then extracted first element of json to get latest commit.
But some  data is different from what is there in bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet to get the latest commit for a particular file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import tempfile
import sys
import urllib2
import json
import base64
import logging
import re
import pprint
import requests
import subprocess

projectKey= "FW"
repoKey = "fw"
branch = "master"
pathToVersionProperties = "core/CruiseControl/CI_version.properties"
localVersionProperties = "CI_version.properties"
bitbucketBaseUrl = "https://bitbucket.company.com/rest/api/latest"
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')

    def getLatestCommit():
        restEndpoint = "{}/projects/{}/repos/{}/commits?path={}".format(bitbucketBaseUrl, projectKey, repoKey, pathToVersionProperties)
        logging.info("REST endpoint : {}".format(restEndpoint))

         request = urllib2.Request(restEndpoint)
         request.add_header("Authorization", "Bearer %s" % os.environ["PAT"])
         result = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(request).read())
         latestCommit = result["values"][0]["displayId"]
         if(len(latestCommit) > 0):
              logging.info("Latest commit: {}".format(latestCommit))
         else:
             logging.error("Commit hash is empty, failed to retrieve latest commit")
             sys.exit(1)
    return latestCommit

 latestCommit = getLatestCommit()
```

You can install stashy with `pip install stashy`.

Comment: This works fine with branch name without forward slash but fails in branch -name with forward slash like feature/abc and in your script you didn't mentioned branch in resturl.